# how to give check boxes for json response objects in select tag?

Tags: ajax, json, html, thymeleaf

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
      $('#state').change(function(event) {
       var $c=$("#state").val();
       $.get('getCities',{id:$c},function(responseJson) {
           var $select = $("#city");                           
           $select.find('option').remove();
           $.each(responseJson, function(key, value) { 
               $('<option ></option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($select);                   
           });
        });
    });
});       

</script>
```

```
<form action="postingRequirementSaving" th:object="${PostRequirementCommand}">

        <label>State:</label> 
        <select th:field="*{stateid}" id="state">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">&ndash; Select an option &ndash;</option>
            <option th:each="var :${state}" th:value="${var.stateid}" th:text="${var.statename}"></option>
        </select> <span class="error"></span>

        <label>City:</label>
        <select th:field="*{city}">
            <option value="0">Select City</option>
        </select>
</form>
```

Json response is not supporting multiple select jquery plugin.
please can any one help me to resolve it.

i'm using spring hibernate frame work.
when i'm using static data it works fine, but when it comes dynamic it doesn't working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a plugin you have to initialize the select field after your response loaded.

For example if you use this plugin :

```
 <script src="jquery.multiple.select.js"></script>
```

you will have to initialize your city selector after receiving the jsonResponse. And also in above code you have to add a id to the selector.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('#state').change(function(event) {
   var $c=$("#state").val();
   $.get('getCities',{id:$c},function(responseJson) {
       var $select = $("#city");                           
       $select.find('option').remove();
       $.each(responseJson, function(key, value) { 
           $('<option ></option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($select);                   
       });
       $select.multipleSelect();
    });
});
});
</script>
```